# dtype comparison: == and isin produce different results for "object"

Tags: python, pandas

Minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': ['d', 'e', 'f']})
df

   x  y  z
0  a  1  d
1  b  2  e
2  c  3  f

df.dtypes

x    object
y     int64
z    object
dtype: object
```

The idea is to filter out columns which are of `object` type. I know this can be done using `select_dtypes`, the motivation behind this question is to examine the weird behaviour behind what I'm about to show you.

`==` (and as a consequence, `.eq`) work for comparing a specific type.

```
df.dtypes == object

x     True
y    False
z     True
dtype: bool
```

However, `isin` does not:

```
df.dtypes.isin([object])
df.dtypes.isin(['object'])

x    False
y    False
z    False
dtype: bool
```

OTOH, creating a `np.dtype` object and passing that *does*.

```
df.dtypes.isin([np.dtype('O')])

x     True
y    False
z     True
dtype: bool
```

`np.isin` works here, so there's no reason for this to behave any differently.

```
np.isin(df.dtypes, object)
array([ True, False,  True])

np.isin(df.dtypes, 'object')
array([ True, False,  True])
```

`isin` seems to be causing trouble when checking for object types only. `df.dtypes.isin(['int'])` gives the expected result.

As a side note, I'm running these tests on 0.24.

```
pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

Is this a bug, or expected behaviour?

Comment: `df.dtypes.isin(['object'])` yields the correct output in 0.24.2.

Comment: @QuangHoang not in 0.24 apparently. This question came about because I can't repro in 0.20.3 in chat

Comment: This works for me in `'0.24.2'`

Comment: @G.Anderson 0.24.2 still gives the unexpected answer for `isin[object]` on my computer.

Comment: @both: Are you sure? I just updated with my version. It does not work on 0.24.2. Perhaps a regression bug.

Comment: @cs95 `np.isin` (well, `np.in1d`) is used for *most* `isin` cases for series lookups.  There is an explicit check that uses something different for object dtypes.  I think that is probably where the issue (and different behavior) arises

Comment: On my computer, `df.dtypes.isin([object,int])` gives all `False`, while `df.dtypes.isin(['object', 'int'])` gives `True, False, True`. Weird

Comment: @QuangHoang the issue is with `object` dtype, unfortunately. `int` seems to work. Just realised as I was writing the post.

Comment: To clarify, it works _with_ quotes, but not without quotes for me. `df.dtypes.isin(['object'])` works as expected, `df.dtypes.isin([object])` does not

Comment: That's weird, for me both _don't_ work. @G.Anderson

Comment: @G.Anderson [not for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtF2N.png)

Comment: @Erfan update your pandas , or `df.dtypes.map(lambda x: x.name).isin(['object'])`

Comment: I have `0.24.2` @WeNYoBen

Comment: Ummmm thought you have old version . @Erfan

Comment: I have the [same](https://imgur.com/vEgLru8) as @cs95

Comment: @cs95 `df.dtypes.isin(['object']).tolist() [True, False, True] pd.__version__ '0.24.2'`

Comment: I take that back. It works in Jupyter, but not in console for me ::sigh:: Which is even worse.

Comment: This probably comes down to `hash(np.dtype('O'))` and `hash(object)` being different, and `isin` relying on hash tables in this case.  In 0.20.3 this may have done down a separate code path depending on your python and numpy version that relies on `np.in1d`, which appears to work (i.e. `np.in1d(df.dtypes.values, [object])`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This comes down to `pandas.Series.isin` relying on hash tables [in this case](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/649ad5c91aabb95d7f200eec84b82cae1459fc65/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L410-L415) whereas in 0.20.3 this could have gone down a different code path and used `np.in1d` [depending on your version of python/numpy](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.20.x/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L404-L406).

Note that the hashes of `np.dtype('O')` and `object` are different, which explains the current failure:

```
In [2]: hash(np.dtype('O'))
Out[2]: 7065344498483383396

In [3]: hash(object)
Out[3]: 108607961
```

It looks like `np.in1d` is doing [direct equality comparisons](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ce779dc607baa0630095dc456f5b9ad001095cca/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L559-L568) for objects, and the equality with `object`/`'object'` is built into the definition of `np.dtype('O')` independent of hashes.

It also illustrates a larger issue with `isin` for pandas: objects that compare equally but have different hashes will fail `isin` for the small input case.  Consider the following class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, hash_val):
        self.hash_val = hash_val

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash_val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Foo)
```

Then we get:

```
In [5]: s = pd.Series([Foo(0), Foo(1), Foo(2)])

In [6]: s == Foo(3)
Out[6]:
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool

In [7]: s.isin([Foo(3)])
Out[7]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

In [8]: np.in1d(s.values, [Foo(3)])
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Is this a bug? Probably, but I'm guessing it'd be a low priority item to fix, given that this is a bit of a corner case and likely non-trivial to fix in a performant manner (i.e. the current implementation has a comment indicating that object dtypes shouldn't be passed to `np.in1d` as it could raise, so simply delegating to `np.in1d` won't work).

Comment: `dtype` comparison is completely nuts and shouldn't behave the way it does, but too much existing code would break if the NumPy devs tried to change things now. As this case demonstrates, it's a bad idea to rely on how dtypes compare to objects that aren't instances of `numpy.dtype`.

Comment: FYI an issue was raised in 2020 related to this problem: [incosistencies in dataframe.dtype.isin() - I am getting inconsistent with different runs on same code.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32443)