# Why is df.dtypes.isin not giving expected results when passed a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I want to check that all the dtypes of a dataframe are contained in a subset of dtypes which I specify.

I thought this might be a good way to do that but getting unexpected results:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1., 2., 3.], 'B': [100, 101, 102], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
assert df.dtypes.A == 'float64'
assert df.dtypes.B == 'int64'
assert df.dtypes.C == 'object'
print(df.dtypes.isin(['int64', 'float64']))
```

Output

```
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

In fact, the results seem to vary each time I run the script.  Sometimes I get this:

```
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Sometimes this:

```
A    False
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Clearly, `df.dtypes.isin` was not meant to be used this way.

The following works as expected, so I suspect this is something to do with my use of strings in place of the dtype objects:

```
df.dtypes.isin([np.dtype('float64'), np.dtype('int64')])
```

(I realize I could use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas-dataframe-select-dtypes) if I wanted to select the columns of a certain type or [`is_numeric_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html) if I wanted to check all columns are a numeric type, but that is not what I want to do.)

**Additional Info**

People in the comments are saying it is not reproducible.  Here is a copy of my console output.

```
(base) Mac-mini-2:stackoverflow username$ python pandas_dtypes_isin.py
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
(base) Mac-mini-2:stackoverflow username$ python pandas_dtypes_isin.py
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
(base) Mac-mini-2:stackoverflow username$ python pandas_dtypes_isin.py
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
(base) Mac-mini-2:stackoverflow username$ python pandas_dtypes_isin.py
A     True
B     True
C    False
dtype: bool
(base) Mac-mini-2:stackoverflow username$ cat pandas_dtypes_isin.py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1., 2., 3.], 'B': [100, 101, 102], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
assert df.dtypes.A == 'float64'
assert df.dtypes.B == 'int64'
assert df.dtypes.C == 'object'
print(df.dtypes.isin(['int64', 'float64']))
```

Comment: @BigBen Are you sure?  I find it is reproducible.  I am using Pandas 2.0.3 and Python 3.9.15.

Comment: I get `True`, `False`, `False` running pandas `2.0.3`, python `3.11.5`.  I was thinking maybe something truthy was happening, but it's odd. Removing either `float64` OR `int64` both cause `False`, `False`, `False`, which, on the surface, makes no sense.

Comment: I can reproduce the (issue?) on Jupyter. [After each restart, I get different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgwpv.gif).

Comment: I can reproduce in Spyder, like @Timeless I have to restart the kernel to get different values.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486413/2221001) might have this covered.

Comment: `df.dtypes.isin(map(np.dtype, ['int64', 'float64']))` Should work for you.

Comment: @JNevill, reading the comments on that other answer, it appears they didn't realize the output of `df.dtypes.isin` varies with each execution of the kernel. In my opinion this makes the behaviour even more of a concern than simply the confusion it causes—a data science tool like Pandas should not be allowing randomness to 'leak' into the execution.

Comment: Looks like this was raised as an issue in 2020: [incosistencies in dataframe.dtype.isin() - I am getting inconsistent with different runs on same code.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32443)

Comment: @Bill, reading into this more, I totally agree. `isin()` using hash explains a bit of the issue. I think the mixed approach of the np.datatype and pd methods of allowing string as well as dtype object in some of the arguments only adds to the confusion, and then the totally crazy issue of jupyter kernel restarts (or python file rerun) causing different behavior is the icing on the cake.